# What observatories provide data similar to USNO?

Tags: observational-astronomy, data-analysis

USNO (the United States Naval Observatory) generates positions for the celestial bodies (planets, moons,stars) and provides them in the form of `.bsp` files and their Astronomical Almanac.

Is there any alternative open publication produced by EU or other big countries?

Comment: Can you clarify your reference to .bsp files?   What is that format?   I’ve never seen it used for astronomical data.  The only reference I can find online for the `.bsp` file extension is for Quake game engine map files, so I assume you must be referring to something else.

Comment: @ELNJ the [JPL Development Ephemerides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Propulsion_Laboratory_Development_Ephemeris) are in `.bsp` format, see also [1](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/utilities_PC_Linux_32bit.html), [2](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/satellites/)

Comment: this question was also [posted in Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45496/12102) where comments are also being posted, recommend it be closed quickly on one of these sites.

Comment: @uhoh close there, keep here

Comment: @uhoh Thanks for clarifying - looks like there is more file format info [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12506/what-is-the-exact-format-of-the-jpl-ephemeris-files).    But if those are *ephemeris* files, I'm still a little unclear on what is being asked here.  So I guess the question is really asking whether there are non-U.S. sources of planetary ephemerides, and perhaps tabulations of positions (e.g. for a year) - and it's really primarily about solar system bodies, even though stars are mentioned.  Is that correct?

Comment: @ELNJ yes, you're correct. The only calculations I found from US and Russia

Comment: You should add France to your list. The top three organizations regarding modeling the solar system are, in no particular order, the Jet Propulsion Laboratory in Pasadena, California, the Institute of Applied Astronomy in St. Petersburg, Russia, and the Observatory of Paris in France. Note well: The USNO is not in that list.